# jQuery getJSON data not loading into tmpl

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-templates

I am attempting to load some json into a jQuery tmpl.

The page is here: http://stefairclough.com/jsontest/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.getJSON("http://stefairclough.com/jsontest/json.json",
            function(data){
                $("#news_articles").empty();
                $("#news_template").tmpl( data ).appendTo("#news_articles");
            })
            .error(function(xhr) {
                    console.log(xhr)
            });             
});
```

The json is at http://stefairclough.com/jsontest/json.js

I can't seem to figure out why it won't work.

Comment: Please show the relevant code snippets

Answer (score 1):

Your json test file has a trailing ; remove that

```
[
    {"Headline": "Headline Test 1", "Url": "http://stefairclough.com"}, 
    {"Headline": "Headline Test 2", "Url": "http://stefairclough.com"}, 
    {"Headline": "Headline Test 3", "Url": "http://stefairclough.com"}
]; <--- here
```

Comment: Ok that has fixed it Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

just put your JS files above your script template

1.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.tmpl.js"></script>
```

2.

```
<script id="news_template" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
        <div class="news_item">
            <h3>${Headline}</h3>
            <p>Source: <a href="${Url}" target="_blank">${Url}</a>
        </div>
    </script>
```

3. Then

   $(document).ready(function() {

   ```
       $.getJSON("http://stefairclough.com/jsontest/json.js",
               function(data){
                   $("#news_articles").empty();
                   $("#news_template").tmpl( data ).appendTo("#news_articles");
               })
               .error(function(xhr) {
                       console.log(xhr)
               });             
   });
   </script>
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have the script working now, the json was not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your XHR request is failing. Try to provide a JSON header with your JSON file. Try renaming your file :

http://stefairclough.com/jsontest/json.json

Comment: Hi Henry, thanks for the suggestion but I renamed the file and it still doesn't work for me.

Comment: The problem is not about jquery template, but it's about your GetJSON. The file http://stefairclough.com/jsontest/json.js does return a json string, but not a json header. So the jQuery call won't accept it.

Comment: I don't know if you generate the json.js or if it's a static file, deserved by the server, but something is wrong there.

Comment: It's just a static file. I was just doing this to figure it out. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON does not appear to be valid JSON.

Please try linting your JSON using the following: http://pro.jsonlint.com/

Comment: Thanks for your help! the JSON was not valid